# Nginx runs on .com/port but not on .com/

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

I may need a little help here. I feel I am almost there but missed something in my setup.

I can connect to my `.com/3000` to see my local node app running on server.
To connect to .com directly I just need to use proxy_pass so I did

`proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000`;

But it won't run.

I have a nodejs app running on localhost:3000 on server.

Below is my default file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available`

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;


    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }

 }
```

And here's my **nginx.config** file

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '


                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile            on;
tcp_nopush          on;
tcp_nodelay         on;
keepalive_timeout   65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;

include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type        application/octet-stream;

# Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
# See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
# for more information.
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
index   index.html index.htm;

server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  localhost;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
    }

     # redirect server error pages to the static page /40x.html
    #
    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }

}
```

**Update -**

I am on Amazon Ec2 instance. The page at .com displays as

[image]

**For root directive I have tried**

1. `root /var/www/app/index.html` and in this case it will just throw me 404 not found nginx page**
2. `root /var/www/app` and in this case it gives 403 forbidden error**

Comment: What happens when you connect to port 80? What's your error message? Also note that you have `default_server` in both server blocks. Most probably the wrong one wins.

Comment: are you getting correct data with .com:3000 directly. or are you appending app name like .com:300/app1 to access it.

Comment: @SunilBhoi 3000 runs directly and works fine

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I think it hits the `/usr/share/nginx/html` and gives me nginx welcome page. I tried to change this root to something else and it is now giving me 404 nginx page.   For the `default_server` line in both files of server block, please go ahead and mention the corrected version. I am not even sure how default and nginx.conf are playing together. Just sort it out for me

Comment: @kushalvm are you getting default nginx page with .com or is there any error. If its default page then try to add proxy_pass line in default server block

Comment: Ok. And where exactly can I find this `default_server` block?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `default_server` from your `nginx.config`:

```
    listen       80; # default_server;
    listen       [::]:80; # default_server;
```

Then your `default` config file should get the requests. Also, I would only use `server_name _;` for a document root that should be used as a last resort when a request arrives for a domain that is not configured on your server. Use the actual domain name instead of `_`.

Comment: should I remove `default_server` from .conf file or default as well? coz the second change you mentioned is in default file

Comment: I have tried commenting first in nginx.conf and then in default file as well. Doesn't work. Replaced `server_name ` value with actual .com and still the same

Answer (score 0):

That is quite a confusing configuration file layout. I see a couple of things you should try:

Remove the `server` block from nginx configuration.

Make sure your `default` configuration file is saved in `/etc/nginx/conf.d` with a filename ending with `.conf`. This way it will be included in nginx configuration.

The current nginx configuration does not include any files in `sites-available` or `sites-enabled` directories, therefore those files have no effect.

One final tip, you should use `nginx -T` (note the capital T) to check what is the actual configuration nginx uses when all includes are processed.